# Android studio: "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libboost_serialization.so.1.74.0" not found"

Tags: java, android, shared-objects

So I'm working on an Android studio Project with the monero shared object files. After encountering the above error when using the monero functions in my (Java) code, I put the libboost_seialization file into my jniLibs/arm64-v8a directory with the rest of my (working) .so files. When doing so I still get the same error: `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libboost_serialization.so.1.74.0" not found`. I got the file from: http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/b/boost1.74/libboost-serialization1.74.0_1.74.0+ds1-21_arm64.deb

I tried putting it in the lib folder which made no difference. When I tried putting it into just jniLibs I got: `libboost_serialization.so is not an ABI`.